# Python 2.7: how to read only a few lines at a time from a file?

Tags: python, file

For example, I have 2,000 lines in a file, and I want to read 500 lines at a time and do something with these 500 lines before reading another 500 lines. I wonder if anyone would write some quick code for me to learn. Thanks!

Comment: Show us the code you have now and we'll go from there.

Answer (score 7):

You could use a generator to group the lines together, and yield them in a way that is convenient to use in a simple for loop. This might get you started:

```
def chunks_of(iterable, chunk_size=500):
    out = []
    for item in iterable:
        out.append(item)
        if len(out) >= chunk_size:
            yield out
            out = []
    if out:
        yield out
```

You can then use this like:

```
for chunk_of_lines in chunks_of(file('/path/to/file'), chunk_size=500):
    # chunk_of_lines is 500 or fewer lines from the file
```

(Why "500 or fewer"? Because the last chunk might not be 500 lines if the number of lines in the file was not an even multiple of 500.)

**Edit:** Always check the docs first. Here's a recipe from [the itertools docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/itertools.html#recipes)

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

This creates a list of *n* iterators on the iterable (in this case, the file object) -- since they are all iterators on the same underlying object, when one advances, the rest will all advance as well -- and then zips their result. `izip_longest` works like `izip`, but pads its results with the `fillvalue`, rather than simply omitting them, as my `chunks_of` function does.

Comment: I think for someone that is an absolute beginner, the generator solution is too complex. If they can't write a simple loop they aren't going to understand generators and the yield statement.

Comment: @eryksun d'oh! thanks, good point -- and that actually makes more sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to read 500 lines at a time:

```
lines = itertools.islice(file_obj, 500)
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me but i think that this very basic sample will work too:

```
linesToProceed = 500
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = []
    for i,line in enumerate(f):
        if (i + 1) % linesToProceed:
            # do something with lines in lines
            lines = []
        else:
            lines.append(line)
```